# Why can't I use <AVerCapAPI.h> in VC++ 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

`<AVerCapAPI.h>` is provided by avermedia SDK. I use VS2010. When I include this header, it produces many errors like

```
116 IntelliSense: Recognition item "DWORD" is not defined   c:\program files (x86)\avercapturesdk\include\avercapapi.h  
error C4430: lost typed specification - assumed to be int。Notice: C++ do not support default-int    c:\program files (x86)\avercapturesdk\include\avercapapi.h
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Declare `DWORD` before including the header, or include `windef.h` (which is where Windows declares `DWORD`.

```
#include <windef.h>
#include <avercapapi.h>
```